# not getting past form.is_valid to process form in django view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have the following form i populate based on a question id:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    options = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.none(), 
                                    widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        question_id = kwargs.pop('question_id', None)
        if question_id:
            print question_id
            super(QuestionForm, self).__init__()
            question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
            ts = Option.objects.filter(question = question)
            for t in ts:
                print t.name
            self.fields['options'].queryset = Option.objects.filter(question = question)

    def clean(self):
        print 'in clean'
        cleaned_options = self.cleaned_data['options']
        try:
            print cleaned_options
            raise forms.ValidationError('That is not the right answer.  Try again.')
        except:
            return cleaned_options
```

I call it from my view like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        print 'in post'
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, question_id=question.id)
        print '---'
        options = request.POST.getlist('options')
        option = options[0]
        print option
        if form.is_valid():
            print '******'
```

My template looks simply like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    {{ form.errors }}
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I get the option I selected, but I am unable to trigger the clean method to alert the user whether the correct answer is selected or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with the `try` and `except` block in `clean()`?

Comment: put an `else` after `form.is_valid()` where you can `print form.errors` - You will know why the validation is failing

Comment: @AshishKasturia I haven't finished the implementation yet but I can't even make it to the clean method.

Comment: @karthikr the form.errors prints blank / nothing

Comment: Are you basing your observation of "can't even make it to the clean method" on the lack of printing of `'in clean'`?

Comment: @AshishKasturia yes I am

Comment: Is anything else printing?

Comment: @AshishKasturia everything that is not in clean and form_valid is printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues in your `__init__` method.

The one that's causing your actual problem is that you are not passing args and kwargs on to the superclass method. So the form data is never actually assigned, so is_valid can never be true. You should be doing this:

```
super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Just as important, though, that super call should not be indented inside the `if` statement. You need to make that call whatever happens. The easiest fix here would be to move it to before the `if`.

Comment: I now get Key Error for "options" in the form in the template.  Do you know why that is occurring?  Thanks!

Comment: The problem with the options was that form had a validation issue and so wasn't making it to clean.